# CPU usage keeps spiking every ~30s during sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I've recently noticed that my MacBook (Pro, 14,1, running 10.14.6) has significant CPU usage while in sleep, with the CPU usage "spiking" roughly every 30 seconds. This causes the MacBook to overheat in sleep when it lacks ventilation (so when I carry it around) and lose about 20% of battery an hour.

I first noticed this a week ago, when I took my MacBook out and noticed it was overheating significantly (fans were at 7200rpm, trackpad and battery was at 45C).

It appears that the same CPU spikes don't occur while the computer is awake.

I took a few screenshots of iStats which demonstrate the CPU issue. In these images, my computer was asleep until 18:20, then I used it for a few minutes. I switched the "Turn display off after" option to "Never" and left the computer alone for about 10 minutes.

This is the CPU usage:
[image]

This is the CPU load:
[image]

This is the network usage:
[image]

Unfortunately, these graphs do not tell me what was using the CPU during sleep.

I tried turning off Bluetooth usage and put on "Do Not Disturb" during sleep, none of these worked. I had already turned Power Nap off.